# Click Event in Canvas / SVG

Tags: html, canvas

I am playing around with HTML5 Canvas to develop an interactive personal website.
I created a canvas 400x200 and then put a background image on it. Now on top of the BG Image, I have placed 5 more images. Now, my requirement is, depending on the image clicked I want to 1, display a text outside of the canvas, and 2, grey out the other 4 images (more in an animated form).

I am able to accomplish till displaying the images, I am unable to create a click event action. Is it because the whole canvas is treated as one single image? if so would using #usemap work? I tried adding a addEventListener event but nothing is happening.

is there a easier way in SVG to accomplish the same?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add click handler on the canvas using jquery like this

```
$("#canvasId").click(function(e){
    alert("canvas clicked";
}
```

Now you will have to determine the image at which the click event was occurred. If you know the top-left and bottomRight corner of the image you can determine the image on which you had clicked. To determine the mouse location you can use something like following

```
var x = Math.floor((e.pageX-$("#canvasId").offset().left) / 20);
var y = Math.floor((e.pageY-$("#canvasId").offset().top) / 20);
```

Comment: Thanks for your pointer. This actually did help and I tweaked my code a little bit to fit in.

Comment: being new to the forum, I may need guidelines. I did click on the yes button when it asked if your post was useful. Is there a separate accept button ?